# Kotlin Comparison between BufferedReader::readText and String always false

Tags: kotlin, command-line

I read stdin and stderr from the command-line using:

```kotlin
fun runCommand(vararg commands: String): Pair<String, String> {
        val proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands)
        val stdIn = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(proc.inputStream))
        val stdErr = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(proc.errorStream))
        val p = Pair(stdIn.use(BufferedReader::readText).trim(), stdErr.use(BufferedReader::readText).trim())
        stdIn.close();
        stdErr.close();
        return p;
    }
```

This gives me a Pair of <String, String> with the output of stdin and stderr.
However, no matter how I try to compare these Strings to another String, the comparison always returns false.
Things I've tried:

```kotlin
    runCommand("nordvpn", "account").first.compareTo("You are not logged in.")
```

```kotlin
    runCommand("nordvpn", "account").first == "You are not logged in."
```

```kotlin
    runCommand("nordvpn", "account").first.equals("You are not logged in.")
```

Might this have something to do with the encoding?
Or am I just reading the output incorrectly?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the output of the `runCommand`?

Comment: My first thought was line endings, but the `trim()` should take care of those.  I'd suggest printing the strings out as a list of character codes; that should make any differences obvious.

Comment: @gidds Thanks for your great idea! That way I found that for some reason a - CR SP SP CR was in front of the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gidds' comment I was able to find that for some reason the output of the command (stdout) had "-CR SP SP CR" (- CarriageReturn Space Space CarriageReturn" prepended, which I removed with a simple String.drop(5).

Edit: After some more thinking, I assume that the aforementioned charts were responsible for making the output of the command  in the terminal colored (yellow)